# ./configtxgen mychannel.block > test3.json

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

./configtxgen  mychannel.block > test3.json
2019-09-01 15:45:24.878 PKT [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2019-09-01 15:45:24.878 PKT [common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> PANI 002 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
2019-09-01 15:45:24.878 PKT [common/tools/configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 003 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type "" [recovered]
    panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc42054e9a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go

Comment: Please mention what you are doing and what you want to do?

Comment: your question seems unclear, please explain what you want to do and what you've done so far to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need mychannel.block as json format

Follow the steps below in order to get the result

- One can decode this mychannel.block using protolator & configtxlator
  Commands:

**Step1**: GOTO fabricsamples/bin ./configtxlator start

**Step2**: GOTO mychannel.block file location then issue below command

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @mychannel.block http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/decode/common.Block > mychannel.json
```

> I have done the same for sample genesis.block check this
>   http://ideone.com/L1hcRX which contain genesis.block as json format
>   which contain all network information.